# IOS/Objective-C/Core-data: How to detect if new image picked in picker controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimagepickercontroller

For a profile page, I let users choose an image if they want.  Otherwise, the page displays a generic headshot.  In the edit version of the page, it similarly shows the image they pick using the image picker controller or a generic headshot if they have never chosen one.

When I save in core data, if they have chosen image, I save the image as a file and save its name in core data.  That is working.

However, if they have not chosen an image and the generic headshot is showing, I don't want to save anything--either an image or a value for pic name in core data.

Right now, I am grabbing the image name and contents from the view and discovered I am inadvertently saving the generic image view and also the generic image name in core data which causes problems down the line.

How can I grab the image and name if is a chosen image but if only a generic one, detect this so that I don't save anything?

This is abbreviated code I am currently using:

```
 //grab image currently being displayed
 UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
//assign name for pic
 NSString *picname = @"newpic.png";
//***I would like to do following only if the user has chosen a pic, not if it is a generic pic showing.
//save name of pic in contact entity 
     [self.contact setValue:picname forKey:@"pic"];
//use separate saveImageasPicName method to save the image
   [self saveImage:image asPicName:picname];
//****
//save managed object context which puts name of pic in core data
 if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            //saved
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL imageWasPicked;
```

on your viewDidload set it to NO

```
self.imageWasPicked = NO;
```

After you picked the image, set flag to YES

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
// image processing code
self.imageWasPicked = YES;
}
```

and, finally, check this flag - save data or not

```
if (self.wasImagePicked)
{
//grab image currently being displayed
 UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
//assign name for pic
 NSString *picname = @"newpic.png";
//***I would like to do following only if the user has chosen a pic, not if it is a generic pic showing.
//save name of pic in contact entity 
     [self.contact setValue:picname forKey:@"pic"];
//use separate saveImageasPicName method to save the image
   [self saveImage:image asPicName:picname];
//****
//save managed object context which puts name of pic in core data
 if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            //saved
                   } 
}
```

Hope this helps